# What is the first global.asax event that Session is accessible assuming the context handler is IRequiresSessionState or IReadOnlySessionState?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My app sometimes calls `Server.Transfer` in the `Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest` event of the global.asax to act as kind of url rewite.  When this happens and I need to access `Session` I get an HttpException: "Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true..."  I am assuming this is happening because of the event I am calling `Server.Transfer`.  Is that why I am getting the exception?  When should I do the transfer?

Comment: I think session variable are available after execution of Session_Start

Comment: Yes it is created then but is it accessible in all events of subsequent requests?  FYI I think I am on the wrong track here because I tried a few different events and I'm getting the same exception.  Also I only get it when I have to call Server.Transfer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`PostAuthenticateRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postauthenticaterequest.aspx) occurs before the [`AcquireRequestState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.acquirerequeststate.aspx) and the session state should only be available after this event is raised, so if you need to access session state for the request you need to wait for that event.

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx) as a reference.

> 1. ...
> 2. Raise the PostAuthenticateRequest event.
> 3. ...
> 4. Raise the AcquireRequestState event.
> 5. ...

Comment: Thanks for the reference but I am still getting the exception no matter when I call server.transfer.  Is there no session because /blog/someentry does not load up a handler at all?