# Global Variables MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working in an MVC application  using MVC5.  I was wondering about how can I declare a global variable.  I have created variables in global.asax like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Application["Login"] = "Jonh Doe";
```

Also I have created private static members in the controllers.  But I have realized that if two users are browsing the app the value that one store on the variable is shared between the rest.

Any way that i can store variables that are not shared between all instances of the application?

Comment: You're probably looking for [`HttpContext.Session`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: So the only way is to store it on the session? at the end that is what i have ended doing it. but not like you explain, your example is better.

Comment: i have created on the controller this structure
 public string facilitySelected
        {
            get { return Session["Facility"].ToString(); }
            set { Session["Facility"] = value; }
        }

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use session, which is global to the current user only:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["Login"] = "John Doe";
```

However, you won't do that in global.asax because Session is a module that gets initialized at a very specific time ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500681/what-is-the-first-global-asax-event-that-session-is-accessible-assuming-the-cont?rq=1)).  As such, you most likely want to do it in the controller at an appropriate time:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   this.HttpContext.Session["Login"] = "X";
}
```

As an oversimplified example.

Comment: thank you! yes that is what i was doing after realizing that the other approach is shared between all instances of the application.